# merging three data frames based on id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The 3 dataFrames I have are as below:
`df_first = pd.read_csv("first.csv", index_col = "id") df_second = pd.read_csv("second.csv" , index_col = "id") df_third = pd.read_csv("third.csv" , index_col = "id")`

I have indexed them by id as shown above. df_first has two colmns col_1 and col_2, while df_second has two colmns i.e. col_3 and col_4, and df_third has columns as col_5 and col_6. I want to create another dataFrame which has the col_2, col_4, col_6 and one more extra columns which is the sum of all the 3 entries in the row. By using python, how can I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the dataframes by calling [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) e.g.

```py
temp = df1.merge(df2, on='id')
final = df3.merge(temp, on='id')
```

To sum up row values, you can do as following:

```py
final["sum"] = final[col_2] + final[col_4] + final[col_6]
```

Comment: while using this code, the Kernal goes to dead state. Secondly, I want to merge only the columns mentioned in the merged dataFrame, but not all the colmns ... so if you can help me here

Comment: You can filter out the columns you want by doing this:
`df = df[["col_2", "col_4", "col_6"]]`

Comment: The code for merging is just to give you an idea. I would recommend reading the linked documentation page to understand how to implement it to give the result you want.